# localhost socket not connected error with vm

Tags: apache, sockets, ubuntu, vagrant, vagrant-windows

I downloaded vagrant and created a new ubuntu VM. Then I installed apache2 in ubuntu. When I accessed localhost:8080 from my web browser in windows it gave me this error 
   "The webpage at http://localhost:8080/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED"

I am doing my full stack nanodegree from udacity and they said that once apache2 is installed , i should be able to access localhost:8080 and get that apache intro page.

I am very new to all this so please tell me how to fix this.

My VAGRANT FILE:

```
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
      config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: 
      "127.0.0.1"
      end
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the `host_ip` parameter to `0.0.0.0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `host_ip`, if you're using it with `127.0.0.1` you will need to specifically add the `guest_ip` of the VM too.

Anyway you provide this information when you're running multiple VM and wants to forward on the same port on the host (80 in your example), if its not your case, just remote the `host_ip` parameter.

so all following will work

- if you're running a single VM, the easy solution

  ```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  ```
- if you're running multiple VM and want to forward on the same host port

  ```
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, :host => 8080, :guest => 8080, :host_ip => '<VM_IP_bound_to_VM>'
  ```

or

```
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, :host => 8080, :guest => 8080, :guest_ip => '<IP_GUEST_VM>' :host_ip => '127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: How do I find the IP of my VM? Im so new to all this so its all a little confusing

Comment: you can get the IP of the VM by logging into it, but as said just remove the `host_ip` part, it will just be straightforward